# ValueError on migrate Django Database

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Whenever I want to migrate my Django Database I get the error message above.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA'

However, my models are empty. When I check them with `Model.objects.all()` I get `<QuerySet []>`. And when I look at my models at Django Admin, they are empty as well.

So how is it possible that there is any "NA" where there shouldn't be one? And how can I repair my database?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need to show full error stack to start search your trouble

Comment: Any default values defined on fields?

Comment: Try to run `grep -w "NA" */models.py */migrations/*.py`. Expected that all your apps are in `*` directories.

Comment: There is probably a default value for a particular field/column in your models/migration files.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for the original poster:**

Eexactly this is the Python error message after invalid conversion from string 'NA' to integer: `int('NA')`. This exception is expected by running `migrate` command if a field has been created by previous migrations and you have changed later null=True to False or the field type or the default value, but the value is not be not appropriate to the field type. The mistake has been duplicated by `makemigrations` and it is not enough to fix it in `models.py`.

Migrations are compiled to SQL and applied to the database by migrate command, even if some command is not important on an empty table. Imagine that anyone who received your initial migrations could have data still and you would commit an invalid migration and send him what fails only with data. It is better that it fails also for you.

**Fix for you:** You will see the name of application and failed migration exactly before the traceback. You find the invalid default value 'NA' in that migration file "that_app_name/migrations/00..that_migration.py" and eventually still in models.py. The model should be fixed, that migration file and all later migrations should be deleted and run makemigrations again. (These migrations can be deleted because none of them is applied in any database, because could not be applied. Delete is easier in this case than a manual fix, that is also frequently recommended.)

---

**Preparing a text for Django developers:**

It is a very frequent question about an easy typo that can not be easily fixed after mekemigrations. About [twenty similar questions at SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=django+"ValueError:+invalid+literal+for"+default+migration) can be found and about **hundred people participated** on comments and answers to such questions. The type of field is there usually any numeric field or a ForeignKey. Values are e.g. None, 'NULL', '-', 'Not specified', 'DEFAULT VALUE' or a name of default related object. The invalid value is sometimes fixed in models, but remains in migrations and the issue is more unexpected.

The most important related issue is [Add a system check for an invalid default on a model field #25417](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25417). It has been fixed by [71ebcb8](https://github.com/django/django/commit/71ebcb85b931f43865df5b322b2cf06d3da23f69) in Django 1.9a1, but reverted before 1.9 final. An important reason for reverting was a backward compatibility of `check` validation. Default values of some useful models can depend on database data. That works after applying previous migrations, not before. (I imagine e.g. a related object "unknown donor", that is more useful for statistics of donations than a null value.)

I agree that the default values can not be checked by `Field.check()`, that was rejected. My proposal is either of possibilities:

- A) **checked by makemigrations**, in order to not create invalid migrations and to prevent make it more complicated. (That is backward compatible - every existing migration or normal code will continue to work. It could require to apply a previous migration in a special case if the default value depends on a data migration and if it has failed for that reason.
- B) **checked by migrate**, in order to get a more useful error message. The original exception and traceback is useful, but a short text with the table name plus field name should be added.

(could be continued after discussion.)